# Kubuntu 20.04 and ubuntustudio-installer problem at boot

Tags: boot, kubuntu, ubuntu-studio

The subject describes the situation relatively well. New install of Kubuntu 20.04 on a tower computer with an Asus Prime (Z390-a) motherboard. The process using the ubuntustudio-installer worked fine. I have used the installer before, however I added more groups this time, and have never used the installer on this computer.

After a reboot, the computer has since refused to complete a boot. However, I am able to Ctrl Alt F3 to get a terminal, login as user, run startx and get an X session without problems. I can provide more information if I know which logs to look in at /var/log.

---

On a hunch, I booted from the generic kernel, which I had no problems with before, and everything works fine. So, as a kludge, I have set Grub2 to boot the generic kernel as default until I can get sorted out what ever is wrong with the low latency kernel...

Comment: Is your video, by chance, Nvidia?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the proprietary Nvidia driver, and ran into the exact same problem. I also started with a fresh Kubuntu from the ISO, followed by the `ubuntustudio-installer`.

I found that `linux-modules-nvidia-390-5.4.0-37-generic` was installed, but `linux-modules-nvidia-390-5.4.0-37-lowlatency`, `linux-modules-nvidia-390-generic` and `linux-modules-nvidia-390-lowlatency` were not.

First check what's installed:

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep "linux-modules-nvidia"
```

Then, install the corresponding non-version-specific metapackages for generic and lowlatency, which will pull in the proper dependencies. In my case:

```
sudo apt install linux-modules-nvidia-390-generic linux-modules-nvidia-390-lowlatency
```

(You may need to replace `390` with some other number.)